# How to create an SSH tunnel between Ubuntu Server (Virtual Machine) and Mac OS 10.8.5

Tags: macos, ubuntu, ssh, tunnel

I want to create an SSH tunnel between my virtual machine (Ubuntu server 12.04) and my MAC OS, the main thing is i want to access to the Ubuntu server from an external machine without

i have the IP address for the Ubuntu Server : 192.168.248.132

and the IP address of the MAC os : 172.20.3.90

I can access form the mac os to the Ubuntu server, but i want to access to the ubuntu server from an external machine.

Answer (score 0):

Which VM you using? 
You should create Network interface called Bridged Network - for VM Ware.
This way your Ubuntu will get real IP from local DHCP server - router in your case. 
So IP become 172.20.XX.XX.
This should be enough to be accessed from local network.